# How to retain type of runtime loaded Flash component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I a have swf, created in Flash Pro 5.5, that has several child MovieClips on the stage. On one of the children, I have used the Component Definition dialog in an attempt to make that child an instance of the SmartAsset class shown below. I then load the published parent swf into my main application at runtime (using BulkLoader for this). The asset will load in fine, but the child in question is not of type SmartAsset, but rather a vanilla MovieClip. Curiously, it has two dynamic properties added: type (from the SmartAsset class, with the correct value I set in Flash Pro) and the useless componentInspectorSetting. **How do I get Flash to keep the type of this child as SmartAsset?**

The goal is to have designers be able to use the graphical component UI in Flash Pro to assign custom attributes to asset children. The main application can handle these children differently based on these attributes. I can settle for using the dynamic properties that came in, but I would feel better knowing that I could enhance SmartAsset and Flash would keep all functionality because the child was an actual instance of SmartAsset.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SmartAsset extends MovieClip {

        private var _type:String;

        [Inspectable(name="type", variable="type", enumeration="phys_circle,phys_square,phys_polygon,placeholder,proxy,subpart", defaultValue="subpart")]
        public function get type():String {return _type;}
        public function set type(value:String):void {_type = value;}
    }
}
```

Things I have tried without success:

- LoaderContext null or one with ApplicationDomain.currentDomain
- Importing SmartAsset into the main application and using
  registerClassAlias on it.

Comment: you could either a) put the shared classes in a library(swc) that is used by both so they have the same definition for SmartAsset... or b) load using ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.. this puts the definition of SmartAsset in the domain so you can get to it. Then use var SmartAsset:Class = getDefinitionByName("path.to.SmartAsset") as Class; var asset:SmartAsset = myLoadedClip as SmartAsset; trace(asset.type); since it IS a SmartAsset... but you didn't have access to the class in the main app yet.

Comment: a) is less desirable as all assets get bundled which makes update more cumbersome. b) won't work, you took a variable name SmartAsset and tried to use it as a type. Following that line of thought though, I have tried linking both swf's to the same external swc of SmartAsset, but the main app still does know the right type of that child I'm using.

Comment: b will and does work.  If you noticed, I typed the variable to a type Class thus you can say var anything:SmartAsset = new SmartAsset()... or as cast it as I showed you.  try it.. you'll see it does in fact work.

Comment: Um, it fails for two reasons. As you wrote it, the variable SmartAsset is used as the type of var asset. This will not compile in Flash Builder unless you define asset:*. Although, it does surprise me that it is then fine with the cast. Ok, so I did that (and kept the cast), but then it throws the runtime error: "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable SmartAsset is not defined." (meaning getDefinitionByName failed). The intent is for that class definition to come in with the loaded swf, right?

Comment: YAY! ok... so that means that somehow in your flash project the class SmartAsset is not getting assigned to the clip...

Comment: So, next debug step.... in Flash, right click the clip in your library... choose properties.  Then make sure that 1) export for actionscript is checked and 2) the "Class" field has the path to your actionscript path

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I have tried that too in the past. It results in this error: "TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@1bd289e1 to childMC" -- where "childMC" is the name I gave the child Class in the Properties dialog. It's Base Class was SmartAsset. I let Flash create childMC on its own. Apparently, this error is sometimes caused by instances with the same name as their symbol, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Fundamentally, I don't understand why there are two separate dialogs: Properties and Component Definition, or, put another way, isn't a component just a base class? Even understanding this though may not fix the problem.

Comment: ah ok... you need "Base Class" to be flash.display.MovieClip  then "class" will be SmartAsset.

Comment: That doesn't work because I need multiple children to be SmartAssets. And yes, I have tried manually creating a class for each one that extends SmartAsset.